# How can I display the ToolTip of several control elements of a UserControl in a TextBox of another UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

I'm new to this forum and have been trying to teach myself WPF programming for a short time. I am currently trying to redirect several ToolTip texts from one UserControl to a TextBox from another UserControl. In my MainWindow I show the "Button_with_ToolTip_UserControl.xaml" in Grid.Row="0" and the  "Textbox_For_Tooltip_UserControl.xaml" in Grid.Row="1" below. The ToolTip of the upper control elements of my UserControl "Button_with_ToolTip_UserControl.xaml" should be displayed in the TextBox below which was created in the UserControl "Textbox_For_Tooltip_UserControl.xaml". I tried the ToolTipOpening event. This event is also called, but I don't know how to get the text of the ToolTip.

In my "Button_with_ToolTip_UserControl.xaml.cs" I put the event and tried something like that:

```
public partial class Button_with_ToolTip_UserControl : UserControl
{
    private string _toolTipText;
    private Button_with_ToolTip_ViewModel currentToolTip = new Button_with_ToolTip_ViewModel();
    public Button_with_ToolTip_UserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_ToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        _toolTipText = e.OriginalSource.ToolTip.Text;
        currentToolTip.CurrentToolTipText=_toolTipText;
    }
}
```

With "_toolTipText = e.OriginalSource.ToolTip.Text;" I tried to get the ToolTip text to set it to the CurrentToolTipText property. But that's not how it works in terms of syntax. But unfortunately I did not find out how to do it.

Can someone help me with my project or give me a tip. Or is that generally a bad practice?

Comment: It would be easier for you to define your tool tip as a resource and use it in both cases.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I am going to try it